# How to add watch to an exisiting angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the directive as presented in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZ6QyrLNajRgIMSlUqsg?p=preview).

```
app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

The purpose of this directive is to use the datetime picker [here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).
The API provides 2 methods to settings dates: setLocalDate and setDate.
When using the control the model is updated, however when changing the model from the code the view is not updated.
I'm quite a newbie to angular directive, but in my understanding is that I need to add a watch function to the directive and probably use the api functions of the datepicker to set the dates but have no idea how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Omer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, I've made the needed changes and you can find it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/179LpdwKpNm5Vm75jKut?p=preview)

you just add the `$watch` function as the following:

```
app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{dateVal: '=ngModel'},
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            scope.dateVal = e.date;
            scope.$apply();
          });

          scope.$watch('dateVal',function(newVal){
            var picker = $(element).data('datetimepicker');
            picker.setDate(newVal)
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: what does 'val1' mean? does it have to be name of the ng-model?

Comment: @omerbach `val1` is the variable you want to watch in your scope, in the controller you can see i've defined it as `$scope.val1 = new Date(1998, 10, 11, 4, 30);`.
the scope of your directive is the same as the scope of the controller that contains it

Comment: but this approach forces me to call the ng-model in a specific name when ever I want to use this directive in my app.

Comment: how about this:

scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal){
            var picker = $(element).data('datetimepicker');
            picker.setDate(newVal)
          });

is that a better way doing that?

Comment: Ok to achieve this you need to create an isolated scope for your directive I've updated the code to reflect the changes, notice the `scope:{dateVal: '=ngModel'}` in the directive definition and the name of the variable passed to the `$watch` function

Comment: BTW it is recommended to use isolated scopes in your directives to ensure directive reusability